# Creating a Specific Path in React Native

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-svg

I need your help...I am developing a React Native application and the app has some svg components, I've built a circular progress indicator and now I want to add dashed border in. I know I could've use `Circle` and set the `strokeLineCap` attr to 'round', but I want the corners of the dashes to be rounded too. Any ideas on how I could achieve that ?

This is what is expteced:

[image]

This is what I have tried so far yet no success.

```
import React from 'react';
import {  Animated, Easing, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions, SafeAreaView,TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import  Svg, {Circle, Path} from 'react-native-svg';

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('screen');
const CIRCLE_LENGTH = 1000;
const R = CIRCLE_LENGTH / (2 * Math.PI);
const AnimatedCircle = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Circle);
const AnimatedInput = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(TextInput);

export default App  = () => {
  const [playing, setPlaying] = React.useState(true);
  
  const percentage = 75; 
  const duration = 76000;
  const delay = 1000;
  const max = 100;
  const animatedValue =  React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const circleRef = React.useRef();
  const inputRef = React.useRef();

  const animation = (toValue) => {
    return Animated.timing(animatedValue, {
      toValue,
      duration,
      delay, 
      easing: Easing.bezier(.53, .53, .53, .53),
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start( () => {
      animation(toValue === 0 ? percentage: 0);
    });
  };
    
  React.useEffect(() => {
    animation(percentage);
    animatedValue.addListener(v => {
      const maxPerc = (100 * v.value) / max;
      const strokeDashoffset = CIRCLE_LENGTH - (CIRCLE_LENGTH * maxPerc) / 100;
      if(circleRef?.current) {
        circleRef.current.setNativeProps({
          strokeDashoffset,   
        });
      } 
      if(inputRef?.current) {
        inputRef.current.setNativeProps({
          text: `${Math.round(v.value)}`
        })
      }
    });

    return () => {
        animatedValue.removeAllListeners();
    };

  },);

  return(
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.view}>
        <Svg style={{position: 'absolute'}}>
          <Circle
            cx={width/2}
            cy={height/2}
            r={R}
            stroke={'#ccc'}
            strokeWidth={12}
          />
          <AnimatedCircle 
            ref={circleRef}
            cx={width/2}
            cy={height/2}
            r={R}
            stroke={'#3591E7'}
            strokeWidth={12}
            strokeLinecap='round'
            strokeLinejoin='round'
            strokeDasharray={CIRCLE_LENGTH}
            strokeDashoffset={CIRCLE_LENGTH}
          /> 
          <Circle
            cx={width/2}
            cy={height/2}
            r={R-24}
            stroke={'#ccc'}
            strokeWidth={25}
            strokeDasharray={6}
            strokeLinejoin='round'
          />
        </Svg>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
          <Text  style={{color: '#f5f5f5', fontSize: 35}}>▶</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  view: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center', 
    transform: [
      { rotate: '-90deg' }, 
    ],
  },
  button: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 70,
    height: 70,
    left: -150,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#3591E7',
    borderRadius: 100,
    transform: [
      { rotate: '90deg' }, 
    ],
  }
})
```

Comment: You can use this library to archive that https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-circular-progress-indicator

Comment: Hey! Already tried that and still no success